# Object in 100 m distance, Error: Operation on mixed SRID geometries

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I perform the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM "houses" WHERE (ST_Distance(coordinates, 'POINT(-0.374930 39.478400)'::geometry) < 100)
```

To find houses around 100 meter distance from: 39.478400, -0.374930

I'm getting the following error:

```
PG::InternalError: ERROR: Operation on mixed SRID geometries
```

**What is wrong here?**

*`"Coordinates" is of type: geometry "coordinates", limit: {:srid=>4326, :type=>"geometry"}`*

Comment: cross posted and answered [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/419538/object-in-100-m-distance-error-operation-on-mixed-srid-geometries/419540#419540)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The geometry literal `'POINT(-0.374930 39.478400)'::geometry` has no SRID while the geometries in `houses.coordinates` have an SRID of `4326`. You need to pass a geometry with the same SRID, i.e. using [ST_GeomFromText](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_GeomFromText.html):

```
...
WHERE ST_Distance(coordinates, ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-0.374930 39.478400)', 4326)) < 100
```

But keep in mind, that the distance is returned in units of the SRID, which are *degrees* for SRID 4326 not *meters*. To retrieve the distance in meters you could use [ST_DistanceSphere](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_DistanceSphere.html).

Comment: But this query would return houses in a distance of 100 meters right?

Comment: @JohnSmith The query you posted in your question returns (after the SRID error is fixed) houses within a distance of 100 **degrees**, not meters. Use the function `ST_DistanceSphere` if you want to measure the distance in meters.